# Draw Ray From Camera To Mouse Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, ray, mouse-position, topdown

I’ve searched over and over and can’t find any answer that works, and any that seem to be relevant are for 2D.

I’ve put it down to the most basic I can test it, this is the only code besides what comes in a script’s template:

```
void Update()

{

 Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector3.down * 10, Color.red, 10);

}
```

This only creates a Ray directly down from the camera (Top-Down display), but never at the mouse’s position. How do I do this?

If you remove `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` and only put `Input.mousePosition`, the Ray will follow the mouse’s position just fine, except that it won’t be in world position (zoom out to see it).

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out:

```
public class click : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log("good 1");
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 20, Color.white);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if (hit.collider != null) {
                    Debug.Log("good 2");
                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log("bad ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check with the ray colours and the logs in the console if the behvaiour is the one you need.

Comment: Actually yes this works perfectly, thank you